# Tikz - Thick line by overlapping rectangles - How to improve the diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, code-review

I create my diagram with the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns}
%
\pagestyle{empty}
%
\begin{document}
%
\tikzset{
bar cross/.style={rectangle, pattern=north east lines, minimum height=50mm, minimum width=10mm, draw=black, 
                  anchor=north},
bar/.style={rectangle, minimum height=50mm, minimum width=10mm, draw=black,anchor=north}
}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(01)[bar,minimum height=30mm]at(0.0,0){};
  \node[above]at(01.north){$m_1$};
  \node(011)[bar cross,minimum height=20mm]at(0.0,-3){};

  \node(02)[bar,minimum height=5mm]at(1.5,0){};
  \node[above]at(02.north){$m_1$};
  \node(021)[bar cross,minimum height=10mm]at(1.5,-0.5){};
  \node(022)[bar,minimum height=5mm]at(1.5,-1.5){};
  \node(023)[bar cross,minimum height=15mm]at(1.5,-2.0){};
  \node(024)[bar,minimum height=15mm]at(1.5,-3.5){};

  \node(03)[bar cross,minimum height=2.5mm]at(3.0,0){};
  \node[above]at(03.north){$m_3$};
  \node(031)[bar,minimum height=25mm]at(3.0,-0.25){};
  \node(031)[bar cross,minimum height=22.5mm]at(3.0,-2.75){};

  \node(04)[bar,minimum height=32mm]at(4.5,0){};
  \node[above]at(04.north){$m_4$};
  \node(041)[bar cross,minimum height=2.5mm]at(4.5,-3.2){};
  \node(042)[bar,minimum height=15.5mm]at(4.5,-3.45){};

  \node(05)[bar cross,minimum height=10mm]at(6.0,0){};
  \node[above]at(05.north){$m_5$};
  \node(055)[bar,minimum height=40mm]at(6.0,-1){};

  \node(beob)[bar,minimum height=5mm]at(7.5,-2.5){};
  \node[right]at(beob.east){type 1};

  \node(fehl)[bar cross,minimum height=5mm]at(7.5,-3.5){};
  \node[right]at(fehl.east){type 2};

  \draw[->](-5,-5) -- (2.5,-2.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
%
```

I think, that lines where rectangles overlap seem to me very thick, is this right or only my opinion? The arrow shows such a line.

The second question is, how can I improve my diagram, I'm `tikz` beginner and I think the code could be improved.

Comment: I guess that you can use `pgfplots` to produce bars graphs.

Comment: Do you want only the horizontal line splitting the areas? If you want to change the whole rectangle use `line width=1pt` inside its style.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this as a showcase which is admittedly a little too much if you are not familiar with `pgfplots`. But just providing stacked bar plot coordinates you can let it build the graph for you (I just eyeballed the coordinates quickly)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar stacked,
  bar width=1cm,
  stacked ignores zero,
  ymin=0,xmin=0,
  ymax=6,xmax=6,
  enlargelimits=false,
  area legend,
  legend entries={Type 1,Type 2},
  legend style={at={(axis description cs:1.0,0.5)},anchor=west},
  axis lines=none,
]
\addplot[]                         coordinates {(1,0) (2,1.5) (3,0)   (4,1.5) (5,4)};
\addplot[pattern=north west lines] coordinates {(1,2) (2,1.5) (3,2.2) (4,0.2) (5,1)};
\addplot[]                         coordinates {(1,3) (2,0.5) (3,2.5) (4,3.3) (5,0)};
\addplot[pattern=north west lines] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1)   (3,0.3) (4,0)   (5,0)};
\addplot[]                         coordinates {(1,0) (2,0.5) (3,0)   (4,0)   (5,0)};

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}{
\node[above] (a#1) at (axis cs:#1,5){$m_#1$};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are many other details that can be incorporated but I don't want to obfuscate the main idea.

[image]